# is there a good alternative to richtextbox in wpf?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Blend seems to crash when I try to edit the template of a RichTextBox (even blend 3.)

I need an alternative that can display bold, highlighted, italic text
of different colors etc.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: Why not try to figure out why it's crashing instead of looking for another control that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

RichTextBox is for editing formatted text. If you're just trying to display text, you can just use a `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">I am bold</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock> and I am not</TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
```

And if your document is complex enough, you can stick it inside a [`DocumentViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.documentviewer.aspx).

That said, have you tried taking the simplest possible `RichTextBox` and editing the template in Blend? Does that still crash?

Comment: yes i have, but it still crashes. it is a known issue in blend -
trouble is i need a template for this as it is for a LOB application.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be "pure" but you can use the old Windows.Forms RichTextBox inside your WPF window if you prefer it. I've done it and it works pretty well.